# Miriam as the Ancestor of King David

Tags: king-david, genealogy, miriam

We learn that King David was descended from Miriam (the sister of Moshe Rabbenu). See  סוטה (יא ב) Sotah 11A.

Miriam was married to Calev and is Hur's father.  See רש"י שמות פרק כד פסוק יד Rashi Exodus 24:14.

But does anyone trace the lineage down through the 10 or so generations that follow?

Megillath Ruth gives King David's ancestors back to Perez through the fathers, but I canot find any soure to trace King David back to Miriam.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Caleb's brother is Ram ([1 Chronicles 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.2.9)), who is a direct ancestor of David (see the lineage there). As his brother, Caleb couldn't possibly be in the direct line of male ancestors of David, and since she was his wife, neither could Miriam. The [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.11b.22?lang=he&with=Chidushei%20Halachot) offers the solution that one of Caleb and Miriam's female descendants could have married one of David's ancestors, and he was called אֶפְרָתִי out of respect for his maternal ancestor Miriam. Since the Maharsha couldn't name them, I would guess that the identities of David's maternal ancestors are unknown.